# How to specify region when using Amazon S3 functionality in CF9+

Tags: amazon-s3, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am upgrading from CF8 and wanting to use the CF9+ features to access amazon s3.

My files are stored in the amazon region "s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com". How can I specify the region name in the ColdFusion syntax? I have tried a number of variants similar to the following but am not winning.

```
FileExists("s3://#accesskey#:#secretkey#@s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com.mybucket/myfile.pdf")
```

and

```
FileExists("s3://#accesskey#:#secretkey#@mybucket.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/myfile.pdf")
```

The error I get is:

> The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the documentation - you shouldn't have to provide the region as that is dealt with by amazon on there side. It should just be s3://key:secret@bucket/file.doc

Comment: Thank you. I am all good now. Cheers!!!